# I want to convert realtime database to cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Below is the code that I need to convert

```
DatabaseReference driversRef =
     FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("drivers");
driversRef
        .child(currentfirebaseUser!.uid)
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot) {
      if (dataSnapShot.value != null) {
        driversInformation = Drivers.fromSnapshot(dataSnapShot);
      }
    })
```

I have set up cloud store but I can't seem to get the code write to translate what I have to firestore.

This is my try
:

```
driversRef
        .doc(currentfirebaseUser!.uid)
        .collection('earnings')
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      if (value != null) {
        driversInformation = value.toString();
      }
    });
```

below is a picture of database structure
[image]

Comment: Please post a picture/screenshot of your database structure.

Comment: Was your issue resolved? Did the answer below help you? If yes, please upvote/accept it. If no, please let us know here.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra I just added please see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `collection('earning)`  after the `Doc` is wrong. because you can use it in starting & once just like table name.

you can try this

```
final databaseReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
                    databaseReference.collection('drivers').doc(currentfirebaseUser!.uid).snapshots().listen((event) { 
//If you want to listen like streaming 
            
evenyt.data(); //<- access data in <String,dynamic>
    
}
        
            
// If you want to list only once    
var response = await databaseReference.collection('drivers').doc(currentfirebaseUser!.uid).get();
response.data()?['earning'] ?? 0 // access specific key value
```

*here I show you my example similar to you:
I am updating notification badge values when it will change.
here is my cloud firestore [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mxLw.png).*

```
//If you want to listen only once
Future<int> getBadgeCount({required String uid}) async { 
  var response = await databaseReference.collection('Badges').doc(uid).get();
  return (response.data() != null) ? (response.data()?['BadgeCount'] ?? 0) : 0;
}
            
//If you want to listen like streaming       
databaseReference.collection('Badges').where(uid).limit(1).snapshots().listen((response) {
    badgeCount = response.docs.isNotEmpty ? (response.docs.first.data()['BadgeCount'] ?? 0) : 0;

    printLog(message: "BadgeCount: ", variable: badgeCount);
  });
```

}